# Maven unpackage classes from jar dependency when builidn children project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, maven-3

I have two projects ALPHA and BETA. ALPHA project is jar file, on BETA im working. I wanna add classes from ALPHA to BETA using maven. I mean to BETA.jar. Is there way to do this? My pom file is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>BETA</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>ALPHA</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <name>BETA</name>
</project>
```

Comment: Yeah very simply add a dependency in your pom file of BETA ...

Comment: When im uzniping jar BETA i dont see classes of ALPHA but my BETA program is working like his been using them.

Comment: Ok you seemed to misunderstand a thing here. You should not unzip them you can simply add the dependency in your pom file and than the jar file will be on the class path..

Comment: I added my pom file. Like you can see i have added ALPHA as dependency and this classes work fine when im using run project from netbeans. But when im runnig app from command line then i have error Error: Unable to access jarfile ALPHA.jar.

Comment: Have you tried to install your alpha.jar to your local repository?